Lookup across multiple columns (15), output as list corresponding value of cell in same row
I have data extracted from Ko-fi of tickets sold, the original data is listed by purchase transaction and includes customer specific info, a single column of every named product(s) (tickets) purchased within that transaction plus the total number of tickets on the transaction and total value paid
I need to establish how many of each named product ticket a customer has purchased.
As the number of tickets purchased will be converted into number of entries on a digital spinning wheel winner picker.
Ideally I would like to output a single column list of customer names, where the customer name is repeated for each time a certain product was purchased as this list could be cut and paste to picker.
I have delimited the product data from a single column on the use of "|" delimiter, resulting in many extra columns but where the vast amount of cells are increasingly empty. If two of the same product were purchased there is now identical product name data in two columns
I'm unsure how to recombine the delimited data into a customer name list as described above.
The sales are in support of a children's charity and the ticket sales need to be updated on the fly over a number of days to support live stream prize draws so any and all help will be greatly appreciated!
my data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SvyTKNwpz0a_D1XeJRoimpzBOuVB8tBaGEdYUsSxRxQ/edit?usp=sharing

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please [edit] your question and add a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

To unpivot the data, put this formula in cell Sheet2!A1:
=let( 
  unpivot_, lambda(data, numFixedCols, numColsPerGroup, let(k,n(numFixedCols),d,if(k,data,hstack(sequence(rows(data)),data)),f,if(k,k,1),g,numColsPerGroup,s,lambda(r,c,h,w,chooserows(choosecols(d,sequence(1,w,c)),sequence(h,1,r))),h,hstack(s(1,1,1,f),"Label",s(1,f+1,1,g)),i,sequence(1,(columns(d)-f)/g,f+1,g),a,reduce(h,sequence(rows(d)-1,1,2),lambda(a,r,let(x,s(r,1,1,f),b,reduce(tocol(æ,2),i,lambda(y,c,let(z,s(r,c,1,g),if(""=+z,y,vstack(y,hstack(x,s(1,c,1,1),z)))))),vstack(a,b)))),if(k,a,choosecols(a,sequence(1,columns(a)-1,2))))), 

  unpivot_('Transaction_November 2024(1)'!B1:R, 2, 1) 
)

To get the total count of products per customer, put this in cell Sheet2!H1:
=query( 
  A1:E, 
  "select A, count(D) 
   where A is not null group by A", 
  1 
)

To get the count of each product per customer, put this in cell Sheet2!L1:
=query( 
  A1:E, 
  "select A, count(A) 
   where A is not null group by A 
   pivot D", 
  1 
)

See
let(),
lambda() and
query().
